# How can I code a webapp for p2p file sharing without a main server?

Tags: java, p2p, websocket, adobe-cirrus

I am making a website where **coworkers can share files with one another**.

One user chooses a file on his computer.
He leaves his computer on and that web page open.
Other multiple users can download that specified file from his computer.

Specs:

- There are no main servers. The one
  user with the file, his computer is
  the server,
      persay.
- It is all done a website, no program
  for users to download.

Also, I guess what I mean by no main server is that I dont have to actually buy servers for large files. Basically I want to code a nice, no main server p2p network.

Could I use cirrus?

*Would really appreciate any help.
Please & Thanks.*

Answer (score 2):

There is no way of implementing P2P without having some central peers facilitating P2P connections.

Moreover, websites are implemented with servers. If your peers are going to run a web service, they need to be localized on the web. You will some kind of central service to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

> is that I dont have to actually buy servers for large files.

You won't have to. You can serve .torrent files (usually a few kB) from any computer. You could use an open tracker such as http://openbittorrent.com/Open Bittorrent to "use" these bittorrent files. Your employees can then use a torrent client (Vuze, Utorrent, etc.) to download the files...

Another easy way would be using something like Opera Unite.

A web-based, decentralized file sharing the way you mention it, would most likely be very hard to create and maintain.